# How to run a chutzpah test on a .ts file

Tags: testing, typescript, chutzpah

I have been working on TypeScript for a while now, and now I am in the phase where I have written all the modules in TypesScript , I am now working on how to test the TypesScript files, I am using Chutzpah rightnow, can anyone tell me the precise way how to run a tests on a .ts file.

I have tried to read the docs, I am getting confused. 
Please tell how to test the .ts file, I am using Visual Studio right now.

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to be more specific. What are you confused about? - [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

> Please tell how to test the .ts file, I am using Visual Studio right now.

The *relevant* docs live here : https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Running-Unit-Tests-written-in-TypeScript

Definitely check out the examples.

Comment: Also it can be runned in compiled js file, it is taken less time then prepare it for pure ts. 
Also there is a [good test tools in ReSharper](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/03/17/more-typescript-support-in-resharper-8-2/) that make your life easier